# How to loop through a directory in javascript when run locally?

Tags: javascript, html, local

For an offline application in javascript, a portrait face editor, I would like to let a script crawl through a directory containing +300 images. Keep in mind that I run my html and javascript locally, is there any way for me to fix getting all the sources of the images into my javascript. The user also should be able to add images to the directory to be crawled. I cannot use php because not every user can execute php.

I got one solution which requires input from the user and is restricted to certain browsers:
http://protonet.github.io/plupload/examples/drag_and_drop.html

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: You can't. It would be a great security vulnerability if you could access the filesystem using JavaScript running in browser.

Comment: Without being able to execute some code outside of the browser I don't think there is a great solution for this.